# looping that only works for the last row in R

Tags: r, loops

I have been trying to use the same loop for different purposes, and it always shows the last row of the series programmed. I need to select every six columns, starting from the first one and finishing from 25 (to 30)

```
for(i in seq(1,25,by=6)) {
  print(describe(scores[,c(i:i+5)])) 
}
```

The information displayed only corresponds to the columns 25:30; what could be wrong that it doesn't print each series in the loop? 
Thanks!

**EDIT**

There is still a loop that doesn't work, seems for other reasons:

```
P <- array(0, dim=c(1032,7,5))
for(i in seq(1,25,by=6)) {   
  for (j in 1:5) {
    P[,1:6,j] <- scores[,c(i:(i+5))] 
    P[,7,j] <- scores[,j+30]
  }
}
```

The error mesage shown: `Incorrect number of subscripts`. Also tried `flush.console()` with no success.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what `describe` and `scores` are/do? You forgot a bracket, use `c(i:(i+5))`.

Comment: Or just `i:(i+5)`. And I think @sgibb comment could solve your problem.

Comment: Which is the problem exactly? Do you need to store your scores in a new matrix or data frame? Maybe you should define the data frame dimensions, something like `df=data.frame(matrix(nrow=NX,ncol=NY))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all print commands in a loop, you have to add

```
   flush.console()
```

inside the loop after the print command:

```
for(i in seq(1,25,by=6)) {
   print( describe( scores[,i:(i+5)] ) ) 
   flush.console()
}
```

**EDIT**

Seems like this commando

```
P[,1:6,j] <- scores[,c(i:(i+5))]
```

transforms P to a list. Does that help?

Comment: what's 
   
    `dim(scores)`

?

Comment: It is a data frame, 1032x35

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't go into the looping problem, but might be helpful if you just want the output from `describe` (from the `Hmisc`-package?) for those specific columns:

Some example data:

```
scores <- matrix(rep(sample(1:10,10),25),nrow=10,ncol=25)
dimnames(scores) <- list(1:10,LETTERS[1:25])

library(Hmisc)
describe(scores[,seq(1,25,6)])
```

This works since a `for`-loop is already build into the `Hmisc:::describe` function.